# How to prevent JSON serialization and still get the data with Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hibernate, serialization

I'm new at Spring, JPA and Hibernate.
I'm using SpringBoot 2.6.3 and Hibernate 5.6.4

I have a two classes with @ManyToMany relationship, Client and Skill, within the connection table I have extra fields, so, I've created and extra entity called ClientSkill and changed the relationship between the tables as followed:

Client:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ClientSkill> clientSkill;
```

Skill:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "skill", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ClientSkill> clientSkill;
```

ClientSkill

```
 @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id")
    private Skill skill;
```

Now, I need to be able to access through a GET request with the ID of a Client all the client information plus all the Skills associated to him wiht the knowledge_level of each (one of those extra fields of the ClientSkill table). That's where my problem begins, I can't get the **Client_ID** neither the **Skill_Id** because I must use *@JsonIgnore* (or @JsonBackReference) to avoid the serialization loop. I'm sending a sample of the resulted JSON of a GET request:

```
{
"id": 1,
"login": "cli1@gmail.com",
"password": "12345",
"lastLoginDate": null,
"clientSkill": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "CreatedAt": "14/02/2022 15:00",
        "UpdatedAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "knowledgeLevel": 10,
        "createdAt": "2022-02-14T15:00:39.485913"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "CreatedAt": "14/02/2022 15:00",
        "UpdatedAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "knowledgeLevel": 6,
        "createdAt": "2022-02-14T15:00:39.485913"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "CreatedAt": "14/02/2022 15:00",
        "UpdatedAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "knowledgeLevel": 9,
        "createdAt": "2022-02-14T15:00:39.485913"
    }
]
```

}

Now, how can I get rid of this problem, folks?
Thank you all in advance, case some of you need more code samples, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: You probably need to separate your data domain from your API domain in order to control serialization better. In other words, don't use your Data Model in your API model. Create a custom converter or something like that and return different DTOs objects than your Data "DTOs".

Comment: @pringi, yeah, that's a good idea, thank you! 
Actually I've just solved the problem using an intermediary class to generate the PK of ClientSkill and worked reasonably, I just lost the ID of the ClientSkill connection.

Answer (score 0):

Will you try this in the class level?

```
@JsonIdentityInfo( generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id" )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).